# How to compute the inverse Z-transform

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, z-transform, infinite-impulse-response, inverse-problem

How to compute the inverse Z-transform of the form $$ G(z)=\frac{z^{2n}}{a(z^{2n})+b(z^n)+c} $$

I started by taking

$$ F(z^n)=G(z) $$
so
$$ \frac{F(z)}{z}=\frac{z}{az^2+bz+c}$$

This can be solved using the residue function in matlab, and it gives me the f(n) function. How do I get $g(n)$ from this?

Answer (score 0):

Now, the answer is very vague and depends, on the determinant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.

Since we do not know if the poles are real ($\Delta>0$)  or not, equal ($\Delta=0$) or not, we cannot give a close form for the Z Transform.

Once you give more information by editing the question, more details can be given in which will be the final Z Transform of the expression you have.